# Getting CORS error on a self hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, google-chrome, wcf, cors, preflight

I'm trying to implement CORS into my WCF service. I don't have a global.asax file.
So I followed [this solution](https://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html).

Nothing happens, the headers are not added and Chrome still give me an error

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

#### `App.config`

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
        <!--basicHttpBinding-->
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service name="##.ServiceScanClientService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"  contract="##.IServiceScanClientService" />
        </service>      
    </services>

    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="##.BehaviorAttribute, ServiceScan " />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
                <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
                <webHttp />          
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

#### `CustomHeaderMessageInspector`

```cs
public class CustomHeaderMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;
    public CustomHeaderMessageInspector(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        requiredHeaders = headers ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        string displayText = $"Server has received the following message:\n{request}\n";
        Console.WriteLine(displayText);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
        foreach (var item in requiredHeaders)
        {
            httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

#### `BehaviorAttribute`

```cs
public class BehaviorAttribute : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    { }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        var requiredHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders));
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(BehaviorAttribute); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new BehaviorAttribute();
    }
}
```

I then use Ajax to do the http request on the client side.

#### `For exemple`

```js
        $.ajax({
            url: serviceURL,
            timeout: 2000,
            success: function (data) {
                if (onSuccessCallback != undefined) {
                    var result = ResponseHandler(data, onErrorCallback);
                    if (result != false)
                        onSuccessCallback(data.Resultat);
                }

                return true;
            },
            error: function (resultat, statut, error) {
                if (onErrorCallback != undefined) {
                    onErrorCallback(error);
                }
                else
                    throw new Error('Ping Error ' + error);

                return false;
            },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            timeout: delay,
            crossDomain: true
        });
```

I tried to put the dataType to 'JSONP', it worked but since I have also POST request, I didn't kept that solution because it only allow GET.

Comment: Try adding UserAgent http header to the request : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent?force_isolation=true

Comment: I don't undestand how this can help me ? Doesn't the browser provide the user agent  automatically ? By default I have this :   " User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36 "

Comment: Yes when you are using a browser.  When you are doing an http request from client in  c# code it defaults to the users default browser.   So the user may have IE8 as the default while the server may need chrome.  Where in the code do you set the useragent?  The client specifies the browser not the server.